# DigiKam: Transfer XMP Data from grouped JPEG to RAW

Tags: metadata, xmp, digikam

i have a large image collection in DigiKam that consists of grouped JPEG and RAW images. JPEG images are the thing displayed by the group by default.

I'm pretty sure that I configured digikam in a way that applies rating data (stars, colours,...) to all elements in a group, but for some reason, the XMP data for all raw images in my collection is gone. (I don't understand how this happened. If i rate a grouped photo, metadata is applied to both files and i havent touched my settings recently)

**This leaves me with lots of rated JPEGS and grouped, but unrated RAW-Files (with an identical filename).
Is there any way to transfer the XMP data back to the raw images?**

I want to start editing the raws in darktable and dont know how to filter my photos there without metadata on the raw files.

Comment: In the database only or do you want the metadata to be inserted in the RAW file as well? Copying the rating from the JPG to the RAW in the DB would be a SQL request using a SQL browser.

Comment: If you use this command: `exiftool -xmp -b a.jpg > a.xmp` you can extract XMP from JPEG and digicam should read it (and apply) to RAW. Not sure about the rating.

Answer (score 0):

RAW files cannot contain added metadata. You must store it externally, either in an application database, filesystem metadata, or a sidecar file. In your case, darktable must be able to read this data out for RAW files.